# Pycharm subprocess.Popen python under virtualenv

Tags: python, subprocess, pycharm, virtualenv, popen

Calling subprocess.Popen(["python"]) spawns a process as if calling the global 2.7 python, instead of spawning a 3.6 version as defined in the virtualenv.
subprocess.Popen documentation says that execvp is called, but it seems to act as if a new clean shell is calling it.
Is there a way to enforce calling system calls within the code but under the virtualenv?

Running on macOS, project in a virtualenv directory which is recognized by Pycharm (Preferences->Project->Project Interpreter points to the python in the virtualenv). My global python command launches the 2.7 interpreter, but in the virtualenv python will launch the 3.6 interpreter.

Comment: I experienced the exact same problem, running on Mac Catalina with PyCharm v2019.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen([sys.executable])`

[`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) is the Python interpreter running the current script. Using it to run a new script with the same interpreter is pretty natural.

Comment: Would be great to add any explanation though.

Comment: If I understand correctly this is useful only for running commands such as `python myscript.py`?

Comment: @ygesher This is exactly the question — how to run `python myscript.py` using the `python` from the virtualenv.

Comment: Ah yes, but the actual problem the OP ran into is a broader one: namely that the environment is not respected by PyCharm.  I understand how your answer solves the OP's immediate problem, but I was expressing my disappointment that it doesn't address the underlying issue.  In my case, I was trying to run a different binary (`ogr2ogr`) that was present in the virtualenv, so this answer wasn't useful to me